# Authorization failed for user: (null)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using a custom authentication for ASP.NET MVC Core which does not use `Identity`. This is `Startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // Configure IoC container
    // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSettings)).Bind(options));

        // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/anti-request-forgery.html
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.CookieName = options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

        services.AddDbContext<DbSesamContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SesamConnection"));
        });

        services.AddDbContext<TerminalDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TerminalConnection"));
        });

        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddViews()
            .AddRazorViewEngine()
            .AddJsonFormatters();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        // Configure logging
        // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html
        factory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        factory.AddDebug();

        // Serve static files
        // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Enable external authentication provider(s)
        // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html
        //app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "ResWebAuth",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/unauthorized/"),
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
        });

        // Configure ASP.NET MVC
        // https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/index.html
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{*url}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var web = Path.GetFileName(cwd) == "server" ? "../public" : "public";

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseWebRoot(web)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        ...

        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string ReturnUrl)
    {
        ...

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInfo loginInfo)
    {
        if (LoginUser(loginInfo.Username, loginInfo.Password))
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginInfo.Username),
                    new Claim("DbVersion", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbVersion),
                    new Claim("DbUrl", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbUrl),
                    new Claim("DbName", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbName),
                    new Claim("DbUsername", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbUserName),
                    new Claim("DbPasswordHash", loginInfo.Terminal.SesamDbPasswordHash),
                };

            var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");

            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("ResWebAuth", principal);

            //Just redirect to our index after logging in. 
            return Redirect("/");
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet("getchartdata")]
    //[AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult GetChartData()
    {
        ...
    }
```

The log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[3]
      HttpContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: ResWebAuth.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful for user: admin.

...

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/getchartdata/
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed for user: (null).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: ResWebAuth was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Server.Controllers.HomeController.GetChartData (server) in 5.2905ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 10.1037ms 302
```

So basically it successfully authorizes the user in the `Index()` method of the controller but fails to do so in the `GetChartData()` method of the same controller.

There seems to be a difference between `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]` and I do not understand what it is and how to fix it.

Comment: Why are you not using `AddMvc` and instead calling `AddMvcCore`? The following calls do what `AddMvc` does so there is no reason to use `AddMvcCore` here

Comment: This was there by default from the [boilerplate](https://github.com/kriasoft/aspnet-starter-kit) that I used.

Comment: Can you post the full startup class without the constructor?

Comment: Posted the full startup class without the constructor.

Comment: Try using AddMvc instead, that could solve the issue (see [here](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNetCoreSecuritySamples/blob/master/Cookies/src/AspNetCoreAuthentication/Startup.cs))

Comment: This didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Completely unrelated but why are you putting a password hash in a claim?

Comment: I am going to remove it, but I think it does not affect whether or not the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Ok, now I have figured out that `HttpContext` becomes null after the first authorization for some reason. Still haven't figured out why, any suggestions?

Comment: Rather, `HttpContext` is not null, but `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` is null.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core authentication cookie only received once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306931/asp-net-core-authentication-cookie-only-received-once)

Answer (score 12):

For ASP.Net Core 2.0, I added: `app.UseAuthentication();` in [`Startup.Configure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configure-method) and that resolved this error for me.

Reference: [Auth 2.0 Migration announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

---

**Note:** be sure to call `UseAuthentication()` before calling `UseMvc()` in [`Startup.Configure()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup#the-configure-method) as noted in the comments.

> The order that middleware components are added in the Configure method defines the order in which they're invoked on requests, and the reverse order for the response. This ordering is critical for security, performance, and functionality.

Source [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/) -> [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x) -> [Ordering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?tabs=aspnetcore2x#ordering)

Comment: Thanks. For me, I was using `app.UseAuthentication();` at the last of method. I moved that line to the top of method body and it worked